# Explain reason for deadlock in kotlin coroutines

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-multiplatform

While experimenting with kotlin coroutines I encountered a situation where a deadlock occurs which i didnt expect.

I simplified the code to the following minimal code example showing the issues:

```
@Test
    fun deadlockTest() {
        runBlocking {
            val job = launch {
                runBlocking {
                    println("await cancellation")
                    awaitCancellation()
                }
            }
            println("launched job")
            delay(100)
            println("waited a bit")
            job.cancelAndJoin()
            println("canceled and joined")
        }
        assertTrue(true)
    }
```

The result is

```
launched job
await cancellation
waited a bit
```

It never goes beyond the job.cancelAndJoin, as if there were some deadlock.

If i change the code slightly to the following:

```
@Test
    fun fixedDeadlockTest() {
        runBlocking {
            val job = launch {
                withContext(Dispatchers.Default) { // <-- this is the only difference
                    println("awaiting cancellation")
                    awaitCancellation()
                }
            }
            println("launched job")
            delay(100)
            println("waited a bit")
            job.cancelAndJoin()
            println("canceled and joined")
        }
        assertTrue(true)
    }
```

Everything works fine, all lines get printed and the test completes.

The question is: why does this code result in a deadlock, and is it a bad practice to put a runBlocking inside the launch of another runBlocking? (i.e. in your code never use runBlocking, until you actually launch the coroutine from a non-coroutine scope?)

I used the following versions:

- kotlin multiplatform 1.4.32
- kotlinx-coroutines-core version 1.5.0-native-mt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coroutines use so called structured concurrency to support cancellations, exception handling, etc. They are structured into a tree of jobs, so usually, when you create new coroutines they become children of the current coroutine. There are specific responsibilities between parent and children, e.g. cancelling a parent cancels all its children.

However, there are ways to start coroutines that are not attached to the current coroutine. This happens e.g. if you provide a specific `CoroutineScope` or if you use `runBlocking()`. Note that contrary to `launch()` or `async()`, `runBlocking()` does not require to be run from a coroutine. It was designed mainly to bridge non-coroutine and coroutine code, so it creates its coroutines starting from a "root" - they are detached from other coroutines.

For above reason, `cancelAndJoin()` in your example cancels the coroutine running inside `launch()`, but it does not cancel the coroutine running inside `runBlocking()`. "awaitCancellation" coroutine is detached from the "launch" coroutine, so it ignores its cancellations.

Below is my original answer. I was wrong about the main cause of this deadlock, but what I said is still mostly correct and it complements above answer, so I leave it as is. The reason why I was wrong is that I forgot that `runBlocking()` internally uses a thread local variable to store its event loop. That means `runBlocking()` running inside another `runBlocking()` actually share the same event loop / dispatcher, so by suspending at `awaitCancellation()` it could resume from `delay()`. Still, I think it is discouraged to do so.

**Original answer:**

Deadlock happens because outer `runBlocking()` starts a single-threaded coroutine dispatcher to launch coroutines inside it and inner `runBlocking()` blocks this single and only thread.

You are correct, `runBlocking()` is mostly intended for bridging non-coroutine and coroutine code. There is no hard rule that using `runBlocking()` is forbidden inside coroutines, but generally we should avoid blocking inside coroutines, we should suspend instead. `runBlocking()` blocks, so it is discouraged and may result in consequences like above.

Comment: Im still struggeling a bit here, if the inner `runBlocking()` blocks the thread, why am I still able to print the `"waited a bit"` text, but cancelling that job results in a deadlock? The thread isn't blocked when i try to print the text `"waited a bit"`

Comment: Oh, good point. I must admit I was pretty confused with these results. See my updated answer :-)

Comment: Thanks for your additional clarification, it really helps a lot, enough to accept the answer. There still is a final question that remains. If the inner runBlocking creates its own coroutine context, totaly separate from the outer runBlocking context (it only shares its event loop / dispatcher / thread), and I only `cancelAndJoin()` the child coroutine created by the launch, what reason is there for not being able to fully execute this `cancelAndJoin()`?

Comment: Even if in some rare cases `runBlocking()` does not really block the thread entirely, it still blocks the execution of whoever invoked it. Corotuine inside inner `runBlocking()` does not finish, so `runBlocking()` itself does not finish. "launch" coroutine waits at `runBlocking()` forever. You can confirm this by putting the body of `launch()` inside `try...finally` and add some logging in `finally` - you will see that the coroutine inside `launch()` never gets past `runBlocking()` point.

Comment: And because coroutine cancellations are cooperative, they aren't enforced, sometimes you cancel something, but it still does not finish. It seems `runBlocking()` does not cooperate, it does not care about the fact that the invoking coroutine was cancelled (which makes sense, because again - it was not meant to be used from a coroutine). I know this all sounds overcomplicated, but I think this is really a consequence of using `runBlocking()` from inside coroutines. It may result in some really weird behavior.